# Modifying a Swing component based on PropertyChangeEvent from separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

If I understand correctly, when I modify a Swing component directly from another thread, that action should be placed on the EDT's event queue to prevent synchronization issues with the GUI:

```
public class SwingFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField _textField;

    public SwingFrame() {
        _textField = new JTextField();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SomeRunnable(_textField));
        thread.start();
    }
}

public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final JTextField _textField;

    public SomeRunnable(final JTextField textField) {
        _textField = textField;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // _textField.setText("Goodbye, Swing!"); /* wrong */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _textField.setText("Hello, Swing!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My question is, do I need to follow this same idiom when the Swing component is not modified directly within the non-EDT thread, but instead by a PropertyChangeListener executing on the EDT that receives a PropertyChangeEvent from another thread?

```
public class SwingFrame extends JFrame implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private JTextField _textField;

    public SwingFrame() {
        _textField = new JTextField();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new SomeRunnable());
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("text")) {
            _textField.setText(String.valueOf(evt.getNewValue()));
        }
    }
}

public class SomeRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final PropertyChangeSupport _propertyChangeSupport;

    public SomeRunnable() {
        _propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Ok? Or wrap in EventQueue.invokeLater()?
      _propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("text", null, "Hello, Swing!");
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like there's anything in PropertyChangeSupport that would make it inherently "Swing safe", but I don't want to clutter up my code with unnecessary calls to EventQueue.invokeLater() if they're not required.

Comment: @nachokk I can understand where you're coming from - wrapping the code that accesses the Swing component directly would essentially make it the same as the first example.  But my question has more to do with whether or not it's necessary to wrap _either_ call, and if so, why or why not?

Comment: I *"believe"* that `setText` is one of the few thread safe calls you can make in Swing, BUT this would need to verified.  I always err on the side of caution and do everything within the EDT, it's just simpler to remember

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used `setText` as an example for the SSCCE without thinking, oops - I was actually trying to exemplify a non-threadsafe operation.

Comment: As I said *"I believe"*, that doesn't make it fact ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `AWTEvent` objects are processed from the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, all other types of events are generally raised manually (generally using a `for-loop` and a list of registered listeners).

This means, in the context of your example, the property change event would actually be triggered outside of the EDT.  Because most Swing components assume that they are being notified within the EDT, this is indeed dangerous.

Now, you *could* modify any of your `PropertyChangeListener`s to check that they are being executed within the context of the EDT, but what you can't do is change how other registered listeners might work.

If you need to do this (I would question the reason's why), you should wrap the `firePropertyChange` in an `invokeLater` call to re-sync it back to the EDT.

Equally, you could use a `SwingWorker` and `publish` the changes so that they are `processed` within the EDT for you...

Comment: Good explanation, thanks.  I've just taken a look at the way `SwingWorker` handles this, and it looks like the implementation is similar to what you suggested - it extends `PropertyChangeSupport` into a new class that checks to see if it is executing on the EDT, and if not, wraps the `firePropertyChange` method in an `invokeLater`.

Comment: I would consider SwingWorker to be the exception to the rule